# 'Set' in undefined error in core javascript code (IE 11 vs IE 10)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I've a piece of code that works fine in IE11 but as soon as I use "Emulation" and select IE10, I get the following error message:

[image]

Here, 4.5 refers to https://js.arcgis.com/4.5/

And on further investigating that line, here is what I get:

[image]

The code that is giving me trouble is:

```
require([       
    "esri/WebMap"
],
  function (WebMap) {
     var webmap = new WebMap({
       portalItem: {id: "<some long id>"}
     });        
});
```

The puzzling fact is that this code had worked fine until yesterday (even on IE 10) but started giving problems now. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: `Set` is not available in IE10

Comment: But why suddenly? It was available up until yesterday.

Comment: Similar issue discussed on ESRI forum [thread](https://community.esri.com/thread/196396-set-is-undefined-api-v-43-internet-explorer-only)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it seemed to work for you earlier. It shouldn't have...

Either way, IE10 is not supported with version 4.x of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript - see https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/system-requirements/index.html#supported-browsers